# Pagination on custom Wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have problem to change content on page when for ex. url change from

/?page_id=55&paged=1 to /?page_id=55&paged=2...

So I have problem to display next/previous page content, it just show first 4 post on page and when I click next nothing hapend with content just url change.

Here is my blog template:

```
<?php

/* 
   Template Name: Blog 
 */

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row main-part">

  <?php
$args = array(
                'category_name' => 'blog',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => 4
            );
$args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;
?>

<?php 
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        $custom_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">


            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>



            <p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </p>
                         <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" role="button">View details »</a></p>



 </div>
    <?php endwhile;endif; ?>
            <?php
wp_reset_postdata();
 wp_reset_query();
// Custom query loop pagination
previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $custom_query->max_num_pages );

// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
        </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/talentedaamer/Bootstrap-wordpress-pagination/

Comment: Solved here was problem:$args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;   solution: $args['page'] = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;